# Where does SVN update from?

Tags: svn

We have this work flow at my new job:

```
trunk code on server   --is copied to->    personal branch on server
                                                    |
                                              is checked out to
                                                    |
                                                    V
                                           local PC for development
```

And after a while other people make changes to the trunk code.  So if I go to my local PC copy and type:

svn update

Does it update from the trunk, or from the branch copy on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the working copy was [checked out](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.initial.html) from a branch and you did not switch it to another branch or trunk, then running [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) fetches changes made to that branch. You can check the repository URL associated with your working copy by running [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) in your working copy.

When you want to sync your branch with a trunk, you should [sync changes made to trunk with your branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync). Sync merges are automatic with modern Subversion clients.

*Here `svn info` shows the URL associated with your working copy, repository-relative URL, and the root URL of the repository.*
[image]

Comment: I hereby declare this the satisfactory answer.